# node_modules not installed when running 'vsce package' command

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules, vscode-extensions

I wrote a VSCode extension and am trying to publish it locally via `vsce package`. When I install my app through the VSIX file, there's no 'node_modules' folder inside my extension which leads to my extension not loading correctly because no modules are found

I have checked that my required dependencies are indeed inside `dependencies` and not `peerDependencies` or `devDependencies`. I should note that I have a `.vscodeingore` file containing the following:

```
.vscode/**
.vscode-test/**
out/test/**
src/**
.gitignore
vsc-extension-quickstart.md
**/tsconfig.json
**/tslint.json
**/*.map
**/*.ts
node_modules
webpack.config.js
```

I would like that my node_modules be installed and I would see a "node_modules" folder inside my './vscode/extensions/' folder.

Thanks!

Comment: I mean... `node_modules` is ignored, so yes, it's not going to be packaged. I don't think `vsce` cares what "kind" of dependency it is.

Comment: @Gama11 that's what I thought as well, but what made me confused is this part of the documentation: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension
Take a look at the "Publishing" sub section. In the example, node_modules are excluded.

In my understanding, the best practice is no exclude them and then let the extension installer run npm install. That way our extension stays relatively small

Comment: Best practice is to _bundle_ the dependencies using webpack (which is what that entire page is about). Then `node_modules` can be ignored because it's simply not needed anymore.